# Let R be a commutative ring with identity. Prove: every nilpotent is inside every prime ideal.

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let R be a commutative ring with identity.

**Prove:** every nilpotent is inside every prime ideal.

*Don't know what to use with this problem. Any help is usefull* :)

Comment: Hint: every prime ideal contains $0$

Comment: How about using the definitions? This is a pretty direct result of the definitions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prime ideal and nilpotent question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376500/prime-ideal-and-nilpotent-question) and [Nilpotent ring, prime ideal question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380307/nilpotent-ring-prime-ideal-question)